# Convert quote environment to markdown blockquote using pandoc

Tags: pandoc, markdown, quotation

I am making a ebook and some quotes have more than one paragraph

```
\begin{quote}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis malesuada quis massa a fringilla. Vivamus risus mi, tempus non nisi quis, dictum vulputate leo. Aenean vel blandit lorem. 

Maecenas faucibus velit et ex imperdiet molestie. Sed semper vestibulum diam ut commodo. Suspendisse faucibus tellus id tincidunt vulputate. Ut in leo quis velit gravida varius. Mauris quis purus a mauris aliquam dignissim iaculis nec orci.
\end{quote}
```

and I need that every paragraph has a >, there's some way to do it automatically?

```
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis malesuada quis massa a fringilla. Vivamus risus mi, tempus non nisi quis, dictum vulputate leo. Aenean vel blandit lorem. 
    
> Maecenas faucibus velit et ex imperdiet molestie. Sed semper vestibulum diam ut commodo. Suspendisse faucibus tellus id tincidunt vulputate. Ut in leo quis velit gravida varius. Mauris quis purus a mauris aliquam dignissim iaculis nec orci.
```

Comment: Latex to markdown might be off-topic. But anyway. If I try your example, I get a quotation block with a `>` at the beginning of every line. Many you could elaborate a little what you get and what you want to change

Comment: `pandoc -f latex -t markdown --wrap=none` should give you something very close to that. What problem are you having?